# Android - VideoView Memory Issue

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am new to android and this is the first time I have tried anything with VideoView. I am streaming a couple MP4 files, the first (about 5mb and 1 minute long) opens automatically the other two (about 100mb and 1 hour long) require user interaction and while it plays fine the heap keeps growing and eventually it starts producing memory errors and upon user interaction will force close. I know I am missing something and made a number of mistakes but hope someone will be kind enough to help me resolve these issues and possibly educate me as to what and why. Thank you for your time.

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity implements OnClickListener{ 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,    
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);  
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);  
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController); 

        Uri video = Uri.parse("URL"); 
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();  



        View Button1 = findViewById(R.id.video1);     
        Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        View Button2 = findViewById(R.id.video2);     
        Button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }  



    public void onClick(View view) { 
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.video1:
        Uri video1 = Uri.parse("URL"); 
        videoView.setVideoURI(video1);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start(); 
        Toast.makeText(VideoPlayer.this, "Episode1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break; 
        case R.id.video2:
        Uri video2 = Uri.parse("URL"); 
        videoView.setVideoURI(video2);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        Toast.makeText(VideoPlayer.this, "Episode 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Log Cat:

```
02-12 01:36:18.407 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.u.a(AssetDownloader.java:211)

02-12 01:36:18.407 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.i.d(AdMobURLConnector.java:201)

02-12 01:36:18.407 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.i.run(AdMobURLConnector.java:284)

02-12 01:36:18.407 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)

02-12 01:36:18.407 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)

02-12 01:36:18.407 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:     
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK: 
couldn't create a Bitmap

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:308)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:321)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.u.a(AssetDownloader.java:211)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.i.d(AdMobURLConnector.java:201)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.i.run(AdMobURLConnector.java:284)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058)

02-12 01:36:18.507 21977 25285 E AndroidRuntime: 
Crash logging skipped, alreadylogging another crash

02-12 01:36:18.517 21977 25285 I AdMobSDK: 
assetsDidFailToLoad()

02-12 01:36:18.527 21977 25284 I AdMobSDK: 
assetsDidFailToLoad()

02-12 01:36:38.587 21977 25296 I AdMobSDK: 
No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available (859ms)

02-12 01:37:00.887 21977 25285 E dalvikvm-heap: 
14400-byte external allocation too large for this process.

02-12 01:37:00.907 21977 25285 E         : 
VM won't let us allocate 14400 bytes

02-12 01:37:01.017 21977 25284 E dalvikvm-heap: 
1444-byte external allocation to o large for this process.

02-12 01:37:01.017 21977 25284 E         : 
VM won't let us allocate 1444 bytes

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK: 
couldn't create a Bitmap

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:308)

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:321)

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.u.a(AssetDownloader.java:211)

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.i.d(AdMobURLConnector.java:201)

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.i.run(AdMobURLConnector.java:284)

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)

02-12 01:37:01.057 21977 25285 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK: 
couldn't create a Bitmap

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:308)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:321)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.u.a(AssetDownloader.java:211)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at com.admob.android.ads.i.d(AdMobURLConnector.java:201)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:     
 at com.admob.android.ads.i.run(AdMobURLConnector.java:284)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:     
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)

02-12 01:37:01.137 21977 25284 E AdMobSDK:      
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058)

02-12 01:37:01.157 21977 25284 E AndroidRuntime: 
Crash logging skipped, alreadylogging another crash

02-12 01:37:01.177 21977 25284 I AdMobSDK: 
assetsDidFailToLoad()

02-12 01:37:21.367 21977 25317 I AdMobSDK: 
No fill.  Server replied that no adsare available (914ms)

02-12 01:37:42.327 21977 25326 I AdMobSDK: 
No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available (902ms)

02-12 01:38:00.027 21977 21977 E dalvikvm-heap: 
1024-byte external allocation to o large for this process.

02-12 01:38:00.047 21977 21977 E         : 
VM won't let us allocate 1024 bytes

02-12 01:38:06.747    94   117 W WindowManager: 
Key dispatching timed out sending to com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlayer

02-12 01:38:06.757    94   117 W WindowManager: 
Dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=25 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=53 mFlags=8} to Window{4372b048 Panel:com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false} @ 1297496735963 lw=Window{4372b048 Panel:com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlaye
r paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@43708e60 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tt
s=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{437e9590 Panel:com.test.player.one/com.test
.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false}}}

02-12 01:38:06.767    94   117 W WindowManager: 
Current state:  {{null to Window{4351cc20com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false}
@ 1297503486770 lw=Window{4351cc20 com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.V
ideoPlayer paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@435f0470 fin=false gfw=true e
d=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{437e9590 Panel:com.test.player.one/c
om.test.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false}}}

02-12 01:38:11.777    94   117 W WindowManager: 
Key dispatching timed out sending to com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlayer

02-12 01:38:11.787    94   117 W WindowManager: 
Dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=25 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=53 mFlags=8} to Window{4372b048 Panel:com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false} @ 1297496735963 lw=Window{4372b048 Panel:com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlaye
r paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@43708e60 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tt
s=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{437e9590 Panel:com.test.player.one/com.test
.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false}}}

02-12 01:38:11.787    94   117 W WindowManager: 
Current state:  {{null to Window{4351cc20 com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false}
@ 1297503491791 lw=Window{4351cc20 com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.V
ideoPlayer paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@435f0470 fin=false gfw=true e
d=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{437e9590 Panel:com.test.player.one/c
om.test.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false}}}

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager: 
ANR (application not responding) in process: com.test.player.one

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager: 
Annotation: keyDispatchingTimedOut

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager: CPU usage:

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager: Load: 4.27 / 4.6 / 4.88

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager: CPU usage from 11872ms to 78ms
 ago:

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   system_server: 4% = 3% user
+ 1% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   adbd: 1% = 0% user + 0% kern
el

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0%
kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   com.test.player.one: 0% =
0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   wpa_supplicant: 0% = 0% user
 + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   com.android.inputmethod.lati
n: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   krpcserversd: 0% = 0% user +
 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   kondemand/0: 0% = 0% user +
0% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   servicemanager: 0% = 0% user
 + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   port_bridge: 0% = 0% user +
0% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   dhd_dpc: 0% = 0% user + 0% k
ernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   com.motorola.atcommand: 0% =
 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager:   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% ke
rnel

02-12 01:38:11.887    94   117 I ActivityManager: TOTAL: 9% = 5% user + 3% kerne
l

02-12 01:38:11.897    94   117 I ActivityManager: Removing old ANR trace file fr
om /data/anr/traces.txt

02-12 01:38:12.197    94   117 W WindowManager: No window to dispatch pointer ac
tion 1

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
ANR information:PID:21977/test VideoPlayer / test VideoPlayer

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
Package Name:com.test.player.one

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
shortMsg: ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
longMsg:

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
ANR (application not responding) in process: com.test.player.one

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
Annotation: keyDispatchingTimedOut

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : CPU usage:

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : Load: 4.27 / 4.6 / 4.88

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : CPU usage from 11872ms to 78ms ago:

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   system_server: 4% = 3% user + 1% ke
rnel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   adbd: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   com.test.player.one: 0% = 0% user
 + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   wpa_supplicant: 0% = 0% user + 0% k
ernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% =
 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   krpcserversd: 0% = 0% user + 0% ker
nel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   kondemand/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kern
el

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% k
ernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   port_bridge: 0% = 0% user + 0% kern
el

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   dhd_dpc: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   com.motorola.atcommand: 0% = 0% use
r + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : TOTAL: 9% = 5% user + 3% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
com.android.server.am.ActivityManager
Service$AutomaticANRException: ANR information:PID:21977/test VideoPlayer /
 test VideoPlayer

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
Package Name:com.test.player.one

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
shortMsg: ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
longMsg:

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
ANR (application not responding) in process: com.test.player.one

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : 
Annotation: keyDispatchingTimedOut

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : CPU usage:

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : Load: 4.27 / 4.6 / 4.88

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : CPU usage from 11872ms to 78ms ago:

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   system_server: 4% = 3% user + 1% ke
rnel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   adbd: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   com.test.player.one: 0% = 0% user
 + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   wpa_supplicant: 0% = 0% user + 0% k
ernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% =
 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   krpcserversd: 0% = 0% user + 0% ker
nel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   kondemand/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kern
el

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% k
ernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   port_bridge: 0% = 0% user + 0% kern
el

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   dhd_dpc: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   com.motorola.atcommand: 0% = 0% use
r + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo : TOTAL: 9% = 5% user + 3% kernel

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :      
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$2.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:943)

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :      
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :      
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

02-12 01:38:12.337    94   104 E ANRInfo :      
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1293)

02-12 01:38:12.607    94 25339 I DumpStateReceiver: 
Finished: 3057 bytes read; status 0

02-12 01:38:12.647    94 25339 I DumpStateReceiver: 
Added state dump to 1 crashes

02-12 01:38:58.937   154   360 I TLSStateManager: 
org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SocketChannelImpl@433fecb0: Wrote out 29 bytes of data with 0 bytes remaining.

02-12 02:24:05.567    94   104 I ActivityManager: 
Killing process com.test.player.one (pid=21977) at user's request

02-12 02:24:05.617    94    98 I ActivityManager: 
Process com.test.player.one (pid 21977) has died.

02-12 02:24:05.627    94  3990 I WindowManager: 
WIN DEATH: Window{4351cc20 com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false}

02-12 02:24:05.647    94  4769 I WindowManager: 
WIN DEATH: Window{435200f0 SurfaceView paused=false}

02-12 02:24:05.647    94   249 I WindowManager: 
WIN DEATH: Window{437e9590 Panel:com.test.player.one/com.test.player.one.VideoPlayer paused=false}

02-12 02:24:05.697    94    98 I PowerManagerService: 
keypad run :false:0:0

02-12 02:24:05.697    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
=================================

02-12 02:24:05.707    54 23705 E QCvdec  :                    Open Max Statistic
s

02-12 02:24:05.707    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
=================================

02-12 02:24:05.707    54 23705 E QCvdec  : empty this buffer rate = 23.981506

02-12 02:24:05.707    54 23705 E QCvdec  : empty this buffer total time = 328444
7535

02-12 02:24:05.707    54 23705 E QCvdec  : empty this buffer count = 78766

02-12 02:24:05.717    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
=================================

02-12 02:24:05.717    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
======================

02-12 02:24:05.717    54 23705 E QCvdec  :                      Arm Statistics


02-12 02:24:05.717    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
======================

02-12 02:24:05.717    54 23705 E QCvdec  : Total number of frames decoded = 7876
2

02-12 02:24:05.717    54 23705 E QCvdec  : Average Arm time/frame(ms)     = 0.75
7315

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : Frames Arm Decoded/sec         = 1320
.454102

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
======================

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  :                     Frame Done Statis
tics

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
======================

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : frame done cumulative time     = 1772
355679

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : Frames Done per second         = 44.4
38599

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
======================

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
======================

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  :                       Dsp Statistics

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
======================

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : Total number of frames decoded = 7876
2

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : Average Dsp time/frame(ms)     = 16.7
85728

02-12 02:24:05.727    54 23705 E QCvdec  : Frames Dsp Decoded/sec)        = 59.5
74417

02-12 02:24:05.737    54 23705 E QCvdec  : =====================================
======================

02-12 02:24:05.767    94   113 I PowerManagerService: 
keypad run :false:0:0

02-12 02:24:05.787    54    89 W AudioFlinger: 
write blocked for 195 msecs

02-12 02:24:05.887    94 11446 W InputManagerService: 
Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 21977 uid 10049
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the force close.  Use logcat: open the DDMS perspective in eclipse, or run `adb logcat` from the command line.

Comment: adb logcat info provided. Thanks